# Why is the Ropsten test faucet not working?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

this is the error I am getting. I tried doing it again and again but it doesn't work.

[image: Error]

> Error: 500 {"error":"[ethjs-query] while formatting outputs from RPC '{"value":{"code":-32603,"message":"Too Many Requests","data":{"originalError":{}},"stack":"Error: Too Many Requests\n at eval (/www/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/subproviders/rpc.js:52:23)\n at Request.eval [as _callback] (/www/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/subproviders/rpc.js:54:11)\n at Request.self.callback (/www/node_modules/request/request.js:186:22)\n at Request.emit (events.js:315:20)\n at Request.eval (/www/node_modules/request/request.js:1155:10)\n at Request.emit (events.js:315:20)\n at IncomingMessage.eval (/www/node_modules/request/request.js:1077:12)\n at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:28)\n at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:327:22)\n at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1327:12)"}}'"}

this is the error i am getting when I try to transfer test ethereum to my metamask wallet from the test faucet https://faucet.metamask.io/

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use other faucet for Ropsten testnet like these:

- https://faucet.dimensions.network/
- https://faucet.egorfine.com/
- https://testnet.help/en/ethfaucet/ropsten
- https://ropsten.faucet.kr/
- https://faucet.rpanic.com/

Comment: Note that [Ropsten test network should not be used as it is going to be hopefully stopped in couple of weeks after Ethereum 2.0 migration test](https://twitter.com/peter_szilagyi/status/1530073017287581696).